# How do I get my TextBlock to update text using DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

So I seem to be stuck in a loop (no pun intended).
I created my view which consists of a Button control and a TextBlock control.
I have bound my button to a command which invokes a method from my model.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CounterValue}" Width=" 100" Height="20"></TextBlock>
    <Button Command="{Binding startCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the StartCommand you can ignore this, there is nothing special here

```
class StartCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action _startCommand;
        public StartCommand(Action StartCommand)
        {
            _startCommand = StartCommand;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _startCommand?.Invoke();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

And then we have the model which is a seperate cs file.

```
class CounterModel
    {
        static DispatcherTimer calcTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public StartCommand startCommand { get; } = new StartCommand(Start);

        public CounterModel()
        {
            CounterValue = 10;
        }
        private static int _counterValue;
        public static int CounterValue
        {
            get { return _counterValue; }
            set
            {
                _counterValue = value;
            }
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            //Start some stuff..
            Calculate();
        }

        public static void Calculate()
        {
            calcTimer.Tick += CalcTimer_Tick;
            calcTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            calcTimer.Start();
        }

        private static void CalcTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter
                ("Process", "% Processor Time", "Firefox", true);
            CounterValue = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
        }
    }
```

My issue right now is that when I click my start button it's not doing anything.. Or well it is but my text property is not updating accoringly, the value is not corresponding to the new value that the timer tick event assigns it.
I tried implementing the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I cannot do this.

```
private static int _counterValue;
public static int CounterValue
{
    get { return _counterValue; }
    set
    {
        _counterValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("startCommand");
    }
}
```

Because `OnPropertyChanged` then needs to be static which again would lead me down a whole new rabbit whole that I shouldnt be down in to begin with.

And I need my properties to be static so I can use them in the Tick event which is called from my Calculate Method which is being called inside `Start()`

Starts need to be static because I am calling it from alot of others classes.. Either way..

How do I deal with either my properties being static and using INotifyPropertyChanged oooor.. How do I update the TextBlock text value without `INotifyPropertyChanged`

**Without removing the static modifier in Start()**

And yes I did set the DataContext

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new CounterModel();
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that with a bit more careful design, CounterModel.Start() would not need to be called directly from other classes and would not need to be static (which is the root of your problem). I'd consider looking into patterns that can reduce the sort of tight coupling that you've got going on, while still allowing classes to communicate with each other, such as [mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your scenario here. But isn't the accessibility of your Start() more of a design problem? You can achieve best of both worlds by implementing a singleton pattern to get the value from start method every time you call it, and yet not make Start() static. You can see the example below:

```
 public class CounterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static CounterModel _instance = new CounterModel();

    public static CounterModel Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private CounterModel()
    {
        CounterValue = 10;
        startCommand = new StartCommand(Start);
    }
    static DispatcherTimer calcTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public StartCommand startCommand { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private int _counterValue;
    public int CounterValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _counterValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _counterValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        //Start some stuff..
        Calculate();
    }
    public void Calculate()
    {
        calcTimer.Tick += CalcTimer_Tick;
        calcTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        calcTimer.Start();
    }

    private void CalcTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter
            ("Process", "% Processor Time", "Explorer", true);
        CounterValue = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
    }
}
```

All the required methods need not be static once the singleton pattern is in place, and you can still always get the common instance of it. Now this is how you can call the instance in your MainWindow.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext =  CounterModel.Instance;
    }
```

In your view you make the following change accordingly,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CounterValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="20"></TextBlock>
<Button Command="{Binding startCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

The ICommand looked fine so I haven't added it as part of answer. Do let me know if the approach works for you.